# SQL: sum differences in time until another column is a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table with events and times
e.g.

```
Events         time                    endTime
Tram          2014-11-28 12:35:50.390  2014-11-28 12:43:19.120
Re-Entry      2014-11-28 12:43:19.120  2014-11-28 12:56:07.040
Tram          2014-11-28 12:56:07.040  2014-11-28 13:15:25.060
Dump          2014-11-28 13:15:25.060  2014-11-28 13:50:07.233
Tram          2014-11-28 13:50:07.233  2014-11-28 13:55:17.473
Load          2014-11-28 13:55:17.473  2014-11-28 14:06:55.063
Tram          2014-11-28 14:06:55.063  2014-11-28 14:37:12.100
Dump          2014-11-28 14:37:12.100  2014-11-28 14:37:12.100
```

Is there a way to sum up all the differences between `start` and `endtime` for all the values until the dump event. Then a new line and sum till the next dump?

So i would want a sum from `2014-11-28 14:37:12.100` to `2014-11-28 14:37:12.100`
and then a sum from `2014-11-28 14:37:12.100` to `2014-11-28 14:37:12.100`.

Comment: Can you provide expected output?  Even Gordon Linoff might be asking you for this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff might even VTC this.

Comment: expected out put would be something like row 1 | 1:14:17,                         row 2 |  0:47:05  where the format is h:mm:ss

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this in SQL Server 2012 or newer. This uses running total of count of `dump` events, uses that for grouping and calculates min / max dates from the groups:

```
select
  GRP,
  convert(time, max(endTime) - min(time))
from
(
  select
    sum(case when Events = 'Dump' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by time asc)
      - case when Events = 'Dump' then 1 else 0 end as GRP,
    *
  from
    table1
) X
group by GRP
```

Your example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ee9c/1).

For older versions you can do the same thing with inner select count:

```
select
  GRP,
  convert(time, max(endTime) - min(time))
from
(
  select
    (select count(*) from table1 t2 
      where t2.Events = 'Dump' and t2.time < t1.time) as GRP,
    *
  from
    table1 t1
) X
group by GRP
```

This one in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ee9c/2)

Comment: i run sql server 2012 so the first one worked for me does what i want thanks